# Determine value for default layoutMargins

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

The system changes the `layoutMargins` of the main view, according to size classes

like for small iPhones it's left value is 16, for the X phones it's 20

Besides asking the view controllers for it's layoutMargins 
(which isn't available until the view is displayed and in `viewDidLoad` they are 0),

**how to obtain the default value in a more generic matter?**

i can query the general traits

```
po [UIScreen mainScreen].traitCollection
<UITraitCollection: 0x281de8200; _UITraitNameUserInterfaceIdiom = Phone, _UITraitNameDisplayScale = 2.000000, _UITraitNameDisplayGamut = P3, _UITraitNameHorizontalSizeClass = Compact, _UITraitNameVerticalSizeClass = Regular, _UITraitNameUserInterfaceStyle = 1, _UITraitNameUserInterfaceLayoutDirection = 0, _UITraitNameForceTouchCapability = 1, _UITraitNamePreferredContentSizeCategory = UICTContentSizeCategoryL>
```

but how to obtain the value that is computed for the layoutMargins?